# Data type conversion error from char to int in java

Tags: java

I am trying to convert an array of char to int type but it says can not convert String to int.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

      public class NumberOfDays

 {

    public static void main (String args[]) 

{

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String date = "19/04/2018";
    //System.out.print(date);
    char charArray[] = new char[10];
    int dateInt[] = new int[6];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        charArray[i] = date.charAt(i);
        if (charArray[i] == '/')
            continue;
        dateInt[i] = Integer.parseInt(charArray[i]); //error is here
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < dateInt.length; j++)
        System.out.print(dateInt[j]);
}
}
```

The String is devided into char and then I am trying to convert each index (which is integer value) to int it displays error.
Error Message:

```
NumberOfDays.java:14: error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to String

dateInt[i] = Integer.parseInt(charArray[i]);
                                                           ^

Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to 
get full output

1 error
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because [Integer.parseInt(String s)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) method only takes String as an argument and you are passing character as an argument here.

> dateInt[i] = Character.getNumericValue(date.charAt(i))

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention, that you will have "IndexOutOfBound" exception if you will have different array sizes. Next you use Integer.Parse which requires String as argument. Instead you can use Character.getNumericValue which will convert character.

This is your workable example:

```
public class NumberOfDays
 {
    public static void main (String args[]) 
   {
    String date = "19/04/2018";
    //System.out.print(date);
    int dateInt[] = new int[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (date.charAt(i) == '/')
            continue;
        dateInt[i] = Character.getNumericValue(date.charAt(i));
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < dateInt.length; j++)
        System.out.print(dateInt[j]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert `char` to `int`. Do it like:

```
dateInt[i] = charArray[i] - '0';
```

BTW you can solve your problem gracefully using **regular expression** like below:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String date = "19/04/2018";
int dateInt = Integer.parseInt(date.replaceAll("\\/", ""));
System.out.println(dateInt);
```

Which **outputs**:

```
19042018
```

Comment: This is also very helpful and added information to my knowledge. This is my first experience on Stack over flow and its very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[parseInt](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_parseint.htm) accepts only String arguments, not chars. That's why you are getting this error. You can turn chars to strign via [new String()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String(char[])) but thats not an only error in this code.

Install an IDE, it will help you with trivial bugs.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
dateInt[i] = Integer.parseInt(charArray[i]);
```

attempts to call `Integer.parseInt`, by passing a char value. char is a primitive type and cannot be implicitly converted to String. If you assume that your character is numeric, as apparently you do, then you can convert this to `String`, like this:

```
dateInt[i] = Integer.parseInt(charArray[i] + "");
```

You can also use `Character.getNumericValue` instead, which would make your code cleaner.

On the other hand, if you want to get the character code, then you can simply assign the `char` value into an `int`.